# JSP values are not set to the backing bean

Tags: jsf

I have a JSP page and its backing bean. Values entered on the page are not set to the backing bean.

Following is the sample code

JSP code

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap>
        <b>Script Name:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <h:inputText  id="name" value="#{AddScriptBean.name}" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Backing bean code is

```
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

I guess the button I click to submit the page has something to do with it.

```
<h:commandButton immediate="true"  id="finishButton"  style="display:none;" action="#{AddScriptBean.finish}" >
    <f:verbatim><feat:Button label="Finish" onclick="submitFinishButton()"/>
    </f:verbatim>
</h:commandButton>
```

My faces-config.xml is as follows.

```xml
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/wizards/script/add_script_wizard_done.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>finish</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/ms/contract_delete_closer.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Does the action method of the bean get invoked?

Comment: I found the issue. I am not sure if I can mention it here.

Comment: Which version of JSF 1.x are you using? Also, are you learning JSF by your own/following a tutorial or maintaining a living app?

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have given **immediate="true"** for command button. In that case updating bean values phase will be skipped. Go through [this](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#AddImmediateTrueToUICommandOnly) link for better understanding of JSF lifecycle